# How can I get customers who have all values of "same" name from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem. I have tables:

```
Customer(cid,etc..),
Motorbike(mid, name, etc..)
```

and table

```
Rent(rid,cid, mid, check_in, check_out, etc..).
```

Name of motorbike includes brand (like Yamaha XT660 R, Yamaha R6, Honda CBF125R, etc.)

My task is to find customers who rented all Yamaha or Suzuki motorbikes.
My query:
select c.name, m.name, count(c.name)
from motorbike m, rent r, customer c
where c.cid = r.cid AND r.mid = m.mid and (m.name like 'Yamaha%' or m.name like 'Suzuki%')
group by c.ime

Comment: Please show an example of a query that you have tried for solving this problem.

Comment: select c.name, m.name, count(c.name)
from motorbike m, rent r, costumer c
where c.cid = r.cid AND r.mid = m.mid and (m.name like 'Yamaha%' or m.name like 'Suzuki%')
group by c.ime

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do.  Do you want customers who rented *any* yamaha or suzuki?  Do you want customers who only rented one brand?  Who only rented these two brands?  Do you want customers who rented all possible yamaha models?

Comment: I need costumers who rented Yamaha brand OR Suzuki brand of all motorbikes in database. So if costumer rented Yamaha XT660 and R6 i want him on display. If costumer rented only R6 i dont want him.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you should be able to solve it with a straightforward `JOIN` query:

```
SELECT
    r.rid, m.name, c.*
FROM
    Rent r
    JOIN Motorbike m
        ON r.mid = m.mid
    JOIN Costumer c
        ON r.cid = c.cid
WHERE
    m.name LIKE 'Yamaha%'
    OR m.name LIKE 'Honda%'
ORDER BY
    m.name, r.check_in
```

The above will select the rental ID, bike name and full customer information for each rental for all Yamaha / Honda bikes.

If you want to get a "unique" list of customers that rented said bikes, but not the full rental history, you can leverage `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    c.cid, m.name, COUNT(*) AS num_rentals
FROM
    Rent r
    JOIN Motorbike m
        ON r.mid = m.mid
    JOIN Costumer c
        ON r.cid = c.cid
WHERE
    m.name LIKE 'Yamaha%'
    OR m.name LIKE 'Honda%'
GROUP BY
    c.cid
```

Comment: I get number of rents for same brande. But how to display only those who rented ALL types of motorbike for same brand. Like if costumer rendet R6 and XT660R i want him.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.*,m.mid,m.name as BikeName,R.check_out,R.check_in
FROM Costumer C JOIN
     Rent R ON R.cid=C.cid JOIN
     Motorbike M ON R.bid=M.mid
WHERE m.name LIKE 'Yamaha%'
   OR m.name LIKE 'Honda%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get customers who rented at least on e Yamaha and at least on Suzuki by using `group by`:

```
select c.*
from Rent r join
     Motorbike m
     on r.mid = m.mid join
     Customer c
     on r.cid = c.cid
group by c.id
having sum(m.name LIKE 'Yamaha%') > 0 and
       sum(m.name LIKE 'Honda%') > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of motorcycles of a given type.  You want at least one of each.